# Change TopMost property on a DIFFERENT form?

Tags: c#

So in my program I have a settings page. On the settings page, there is an option to set the program "Always on Top". When this option is checked and unchecked, it properly saves the setting, but it does not actually change TopMost property itself.

The program's main form is called "MainForm", but the settings page is called "SettingsForm". How would I change the "TopMost" property on "MainForm", from within the "SettingsForm"?

Comment: Show us how you are currently trying to do it.

Comment: I'm not currently "trying" to do it... I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to simply give `SettingForm` a reference to `MainForm`, e.g. via a constructor parameter which is then stored to a field where it can later be accessed when necessary.

For example:

```
public class SettingsForm
{
    public SettingsForm(MainForm mainForm)
    {
        this.mainForm = mainForm;
    }

    public void Apple()
    {
        this.mainForm.TopMost = true;
    }

    private readonly MainForm mainForm;
}

public class MainForm
{
    public void Banana()
    {
        var settingsForm = new SettingsForm(this);
        settingsForm.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

(However, it may not be necessary to do this if the owner of `SettingsForm` is already the insntance of `MainForm` but this I cannot tell from what you have given.)

Comment: @JasonAxelrod: I've added an example.

Comment: I tried this... got the following error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 2):

You could create an event on Settings form:

```
public event EventHandler TopMostEvent;

private void OnTopMostEvent()
{
    if (TopMostEvent != null)
    {
       TopMostEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

On `CheckedChanged` event call the method after saving settings:

```
 OnTopMostEvent();
```

And in Main form subscribe to the event and set the forms TopMost property

Answer (score 1):

This is a good place for a mediator pattern. (Similar to a controller) The idea is you have one object that creates all of your windows and passes a reference to itself into each form through the constructor. You can call a method in the mediator from either form and the mediator will focus the MainForm. It's a very common practice in Windows Forms.

So you'll make a mediator class like so:

`public class MyMediator
    {
        Form mainForm {get;set;}
        Form settingsForm{get;set;}`

```
    public MyMediator()
    {
        mainForm = new MainForm(this);
        mainForm.Show();
    }

    ...

    public FocusMainForm() // call this from settings form
    {
        mainForm.TopMost = true;
    }


}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you just said.